# How to convert email address values into numbers?

Tags: sql, database, datatable, casting, type-conversion

Is there any way to convert email address values into numbers?

**Context:** I have a list of EmailAddress in a table where I do not have IDs and I want to generate IDs from EmailAddress so I can use associated IDs as unique identifiers.

I do not want to generate a random number, goal is to generate exact same number each time based on the email value something like:

**Example:**
A sql query that converts "john@email.com" to always "12345"

A sql query that converts "mike@email.com" to always "10101" and so on...

Is there any function that can convert EmailAddress (assuming this can be considered as a string) to a number?

Note - Aim is to NOT have a unique random number, hence not looking for a random ID

Comment: Why don't you use a DB generated ID? It's because you dont want it to be random?

Comment: Hi @DepletedKnowledge exactly, not looking for a random ID because then I'll end up with multiple IDs associated with same email address. Need a number that will stay same, no matter how many times, in any table when email address is covered into a number, it should return exact same number

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, I think the more elegant one is to think of those emails as passwords and hash it.

Hashing is the process of converting an input of any length into a fixed size string of text, using a mathematical function. In SQL, you can use the `HASHBYTES` function for this purpose.

The `HASHBYTES` function in SQL Server can be used to hash a string of characters into a binary hash code of fixed length. The function takes two arguments: the algorithm to use for hashing, and the string to hash. For example, you can use the SHA2_256 algorithm to convert an email address into a 256-bit hash code.

Here's an example of how you can use the `HASHBYTES` function to convert an email address into a unique number:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'john@email.com') AS HashedEmail;
```

This will return a binary hash code. If you want to convert this binary hash code into a number, you can convert it into a big integer like this:

```
SELECT CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:hexBinary(sql:column("hash"))', 'BIGINT') AS HashedEmail
FROM   (SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'john@email.com') AS hash) AS T;
```

This method will give you a unique number for each unique email address, the number will be very large because it's based on a 256-bit hash code. If you need a smaller number, you could use a different hashing algorithm, or you could truncate the hash code, but this would increase the risk of collisions (different email addresses that hash to the same number).

P.S.: The hashing process is not reversible, meaning you cannot retrieve the original email address from the hashed value.

P.S.2: You can also hash the email and probably get the number more easily if you do it in the programming language you're using and not with SQL.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the approach, it is very helpful. One question - the conversion of email address with this method is always return exact same number or each time it'll return a random number?

Comment: Consider the string you're about to hash as the "seed" for the algorithm. Using the same seed will consistently yield the same result. In your case, the seed is the email addresses, ensuring that each email will always produce a distinct ID when hashed. This method allows you to identify the corresponding ID by rehashing the email.

I recommend delving into the concept of hashing. It may appear complex at first, but it serves as a fundamental tool that can illuminate your understanding of the problem. Hashing is also likely to become a crucial skill in your career as a developer.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your response. I tried the query you shared and it was throwing a syntax error so I tried converting it myself and wanted to ask you if you  could please review and confirm? It seems to be working fine for me - `SELECT EmailAddress,
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST(EmailAddress as varchar(25))),2) as ConvertedID,
FROM MY_EmailList_Table `.

Comment: I don't have a reproducible environment right now but looks good to me. Nice one!